# Google column chart Y-axis is not displayng in Polymer 3

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, polymer-3.x

I am very new in Polymer.js and from last 2 days i am trying to implement google column chart in polymer. 
I have tried many things but it is not working. plz help.

**Here is the code:**

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from "../../@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";
import { mixinBehaviors } from "../../@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/class.js";
import '../../google-chart-polymer-3/google-chart.js';

 class wealthManagementTabsLanding extends mixinBehaviors([sbBehaviours.createTabs], PolymerElement) {
static get template() {
return html`
<style>
 :host {
 --google-chart-height: 200px;
 }
 google-chart {
 height: 200px;
 }
</style>
 <div class="mdl-grid" >
        <google-chart id="marketchart"
           options = '{
             "hAxis": { "title":""} ,
             "vAxis": {"title":"Percentage (%)","minValue": 0 ,"maxValue": 100,"format":"percent","ticks":[0,25,50,75,100]},
             "legend": "none",
             "colors": ["#81D4FD","#FFAB8F"],
             "bar": {"groupWidth" : "100em","groupHeight" : "600em"}
             }'  
           data='[["Category","Model","Custom"], 
             ["Equity", 50, 80], 
             ["Bonds", 20, 10], 
             ["Alternate", 10, 5], 
             ["Cash", 20, 5]]'

           ></google-chart>
 </div>
';}


 connectedCallback() {
   super.connectedCallback();
  } 
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Here chart is not displaying Y-axis scale. please tell me how can i fix this or did i missed something .
Thank you.

Comment: is it possible the chart is being drawn in a hidden container, and then shown later? if so, the chart is not able to properly calculate the placement of the labels, and they are not shown. see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482738/5090771)...

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat , i am trying to contact you from morning. 
i have checked hidden container thing also and used ticks also but nothing is working. see my updated code.

Comment: is there more you can share? nothing above seems incorrect...

Comment: plz see my updated code.

Comment: sorry, not sure...